# Vue Axios Request not updating with correct data when user pressed back button in browser

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am building a Vue/Laravel app and running into an issue. When a user loads a page I do a mounted axios GET and grab the data from my database. This works great to populate my data until I have a user press the back button in the browser. It still does the mounted axios GET, but the data is not updated from what the user just saved. This is confusing to me because I am doing a brand new mounted GET call so it feels like it should be the latest data.
I have tried looking up about the browser back button on SO but all the answers seem a bit confusing to me.
Here is my method

```
getDatabase() {
            axios.get(`${this.eventUrl}/shows/loadshows`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                response.data.dates.length ? this.dates = response.data.dates : '';
                response.data.tickets.length ? this.tickets = response.data.tickets[0].tickets : '';
                response.data.showTimes ? this.showTimes = response.data.showTimes : '';
            });
        },
```

here is my mounted

```
 mounted() {
        this.getDatabase();
    },
```

Here is my method in my laravel controller

```
public function loadShows(Event $event)
    {
        $tickets = $event->shows()->with('tickets')->get();
        $dates =  $event->shows()->pluck('date');
        $showTimes = $event->show_times;
        return response()->json(array(
            'dates' => $dates,
            'tickets' => $tickets,
            'showTimes' => $showTimes
        ));
    }
```

If enter a string for showTimes

```
First show is at 12
```

Then press the next button it will go to the next page. If I look at my local database I can see it says first show is at 12.

However if I press the back button it will show nothing. If I reload the page it will then show the First show is at 12.

Comment: Can you share us a snippet? :)

Comment: added some code

Comment: I strongly suspect that your GET calls are being cached. Try adding a time stamp appended to your request (something like, at the end of your URL, ?t=${new Date().getTime()}, not clean but try if that works for you.

Comment: @johnmikelridzz THANK YOU! That solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to help man :) good luck!